# How to fix negative values in predication with Neural Network - Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I have a simple neural network model with 16 columns. I have got the following code to create a ANN.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras

data = pd.read_csv(soruce_code.csv)

features = data.drop('feature1', axis=1)
labels = data['feature1']

features = tf.keras.utils.normalize(features, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy' , metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(features, labels, epochs=100)

model.evaluate(features, labels)
```

This portion of the code runs exactly as expected. When I add the following to include a confusion matrix:

```
confusion_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels, model.predict(features))
print(confusion_matrix)
```

I get the following error code:

```
InvalidArgumentError: `predictions` contains negative values.  
Condition x >= 0 did not hold element-wise:
```

I'm not sure how to continue since the neural set is getting squashed from the sigmoid function, it should not output negative values.

After originally writing the code I included the sigmoid into the model to try and resolve this but it did not work.

Comment: What does `model.predict(features)` look like?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.math.confusion_matrix` function expects binary predictions, but your model is using sigmoid activation, which produces values between 0 and 1.

You can try something like this to set a threshold

```
predictions = (model.predict(features) > 0.5).astype(int)
confusion_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels, predictions)
print(confusion_matrix)
```